# Merging two dataframes with left_join

Tags: r, date, left-join

Merging two dataframes, x and y, with left_join but the elements of the non-merging variables in y are showing as NAs in merged file.

1. Checked if merging variables, **NAME** and **DOB**, were of the same class. The **DOB.x** and **DOB.y** were not. Believing this to be the source of the problem, the **DOB.y** was changed from "POSIXct" to "Date" to match **DOB.x**
2. Trimmed **NAME** in both dataframes
3. Merge returned NAs for the non-merging variables in right dataframe.

library(dplyr)

```
# MRE Codes
# For dataframe B - change dates from POSIXct to Date class to match dataframe A

df2 <- B
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x){
  if(inherits(x,"POSIXct")) as.Date(x) else x
})

# merging of dataframes sda and df2
all <- left_join(sda,df2, by=c("DOB","NAME"))
```

I have narrowed the problem to the NAME variable. A pair of names in the sda and df2 dataframes appear to be exactly the same (equal number of characters and the exact letters), however, when compared to each other, using sda$NAME[a] == df2$NAME[b], the result is FALSE. What could be causing this? No problem with DOB.

Comment: In example data and code (with or without type conversion) I get one `dob` column, not `dob.x` and dob.y`.

Comment: What result are you expecting if B + D do not appear in `y` with the `tel` numbers? Output is what I would expect.

Comment: I don't understand. I run this and get no errors or unexpected-missing values, and the output is as I expect: `z <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), dob = structure(c(31756, 3562, 6353, 8793), class = "Date"), loc = c("DD", "FG", "XV", "HJ"), tel = c("1111155555", NA, "2222266666", NA))`. If you're seeing something different, James, please add your _actual_ output (in a [code block]) and clarify exactly with what you expect.

Comment: The MRE codes work perfectly on the made-up data but not on actual data.  dob.x and dob.y are merely to distinguish between the dates of birth from the x and y datasets.

Comment: `as.Date(as.POSIXct(c("56-12-11","87-05-25"),format="%y-%m-%d"))` gives `[1] "2056-12-10" "1987-05-24"` on my machine, i.e. applying both transformations shifts the day.  This appears to be time zone specific as `as.Date(as.POSIXct(c("56-12-11","87-05-25"),format="%y-%m-%d",tz="America/Montreal"))` gives the expected result `[1] "2056-12-11" "1987-05-25"`

Answer (score 0):

The join issue may be with the default time zone used for creating the `POSIXct` time column and the subsequent conversion back to a date object.  For example:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(c("56-12-11","87-05-25"),format="%y-%m-%d",tz="Australia/Sydney"))
[1] "2056-12-10" "1987-05-24"
```

Whereas changing to a later time zone gives the expected results.

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(c("56-12-11","87-05-25"),format="%y-%m-%d",tz="America/Montreal"))
[1] "2056-12-11" "1987-05-25"
```

Comment: In this instance, the names and dates in the right data frame (y) were copied directly from the x data frame and only the telephone numbers added. X has 123K records while y has just over 2000.